# OPA5: Purpose of "and" in promise returned from waitFor

Tags: jquery, integration-testing, sapui5

I'm kind of new to integration testing with OPA5, so I was reading a [tutorial on the dev guide](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/10592affce3e4f1ba73c3125ee06e0b7.html). There is this `and` included before `iTeardownMyAppFrame()` in the first sample code.

> ```
> // Assertions
> Then.onThePostPage.theTitleShouldDisplayTheName("Jeans").and.iTeardownMyAppFrame();
> ```

I was wondering what `and` exactly does but I couldn't find any documentation about it. The `and` property is included in the promise returned from the [`waitFor`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.test.Opa5.html#waitFor) method of `sap.ui.test.Opa5`, as the image below shows:

[image]

From API reference:

> {jQuery.promise} A promise that gets resolved on success

So I looked at the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) about the promise but I couldn't find anything about `and` there either which indicates that the returned jQuery.promise is extended by OPA5.

`iTeardownMyAppFrame` **without** `and` worked fine as I assumed (since it always returns the same promise). So what is the purpose of `and`? Is it just syntactic sugar? Did someone experience errors because of the missing `and`? Is there any documentation about it that I overlooked?

---

PS: Let me know if you need a minimal example of integration testing with OPA5.

Comment: GitHub issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2757

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not just beginning with OPA myself but as far as I know, the `.and.` is used for chaining. So it is the same as using two `Then` statements.

Comment: You were right. The documentation is also fixed now accordingly: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/28287f0043a3aac930288390601aedc05242d720

Answer (score 1):

The '.and' is a pure syntactical sugar to make the action sound as a fluent English sentence. It is questionable whether using it is a good practice or antipattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a bit on why using `and` could be regarded as an anti-pattern?

Comment: `and` tend to promote joining function calls on a single line that could make it harder to visually comprehend the whole sequence. This is important IMHO as the test snippets are frequently copied around.